# Does [CascadingParameter] affect performance in comparison with [Parameter]?

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a GridCell component, which will be instantiated thousands of times.

The component requires access to its parent components (GridRow and Grid). Value of those parameters should never change.

How does following alternatives compare in terms of performace?

1. Using CascadingParametes

   GridCell:

   ```
   [CascadingParameter(Name = "DataGrid")] DataGrid DataGrid { get; set; }
   [CascadingParameter(Name = "Row")] DataGridRow Row { get; set; }
   ```

   usage in GridRow:

   ```
   <Cell />
   ```
2. Parameters

   GridCell:

   ```
   [Parameter] DataGrid DataGrid { get; set; }
   [Parameter] DataGridRow Row { get; set; }
   ```

   usage in GridRow:

   ```
   <Cell DataGrid="@Grid" Row="@this" >
   ```

Comment: When you say "instantiate it thousands of times" do you mean on the same page or across multiple pages?

Comment: On the same page. grid with 50 visible row and 20 columns is quite common,

Comment: When a component is "attached" to the Renderer RenderTree, the Renderer gets and maintains a list of declared Parameters set on the Component.  When they change, it calls `SetParametersAsync`.  I don't think it matters if they're declared as Cascading or not: it's just a different way of declaring them.  Someone will correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on `IsFixed` attribute:

```xml
<CascadingValue Value="this" IsFixed="true">
    <SomeOtherComponents>
</CascadingValue>
```

> - If the **IsFixed value is false** (the default), then every recipient of the cascaded value sets up a subscription to receive change notifications. In this case, each [CascadingParameter] is substantially **more expensive** than a regular [Parameter] due to the subscription tracking.
> - If the **IsFixed value is true** (for example, `<CascadingValue Value="@someValue" IsFixed="true">` ), then receipients receive the initial value but do not set up any subscription to receive updates. In this case, each [CascadingParameter] is lightweight and **no more expensive** than a regular [Parameter].

Learn about this topic and other performance topics at [Ensure cascading parameters are fixed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-5.0#ensure-cascading-parameters-are-fixed) MS docs.

Comment: Isn't `[CascadingParameter(IsFixed=true)]` faster than `[Parameter]`, since there is no change detection required?

Comment: _'is lightweight and no more expensive'_